# Issue with matching the users Query in hubot coffeescript

Tags: elasticsearch, hubot

I have integrated Slack - Hubot - Elasticsearch. This for querying elasticsearch from slack.

First we are giving alias name to our cluster in hubot to add into its brain.

Now, i mentioned one query in coffescript as below,

```
 robot.hear /nodes (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    if msg.message.user.id is robot.name
      return

    catNodes msg, msg.match[1], (text) ->
      msg.send text
```

When user querys something in slack and where any work matches with nodes, should give me the output.

When i query as " provide me the list of nodes iris" , its giving me correct output.

If someone query as "provide me the list of nodes in iris" its giving me

> Do not recognise the cluster alias: in iris

whatever i give after nodes in query is throwing error output.

How can i solve this...

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on hubot issue tracker actually

https://github.com/github/hubot/issues/1310

extract:

Maybe you could use something like

```
robot.hear /nodes(?: in| for| at| on}? (\w+)/i, (msg) ->
```